# Graceful exit of gunicorn when using a multiprocessing Manager

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am using Bottle+Gunicorn for a multithreaded web application. I have a multiprocessing Manager to handle a shared object's data.

When I terminate (via SIGINT), there are registered atexit functions that are throwing errors.

Is there an ideal way of handling the termination of the webapp? I can call `atexit.unregister(multiprocessing.util._exit_function)` but I do not think that is what I should be doing.

```
from bottle import route, run
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing.managers import SyncManager

class Store(object):
    def __init__(self, manager: SyncManager):
        assert isinstance(manager, SyncManager)
        self.flags = manager.dict(state='off')

    def set_state(self, state: str):
        assert isinstance(state, str)
        self.flags['state'] = state

    def get_state(self) -> str:
        return self.flags['state']

@route('/state', method='GET')
def get_st():
    return store.get_state()

@route('/state/<st>', method='POST')
def set_st(st):
    store.set_state(st)
    return 'OK'

mgr = multiprocessing.Manager()
store = Store(mgr)

run(server='gunicorn', host='0.0.0.0', port=8080, workers=2)
```

```
[2023-11-02 11:34:52 -0400] [276288] [INFO] Handling signal: int
[2023-11-02 11:34:52 -0400] [276303] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 276303)
[2023-11-02 11:34:52 -0400] [276298] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 276298)
Error in atexit._run_exitfuncs:
Error in atexit._run_exitfuncs:
Traceback (most recent call last):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...../multiprocessing/util.py", line 357, in _exit_function
  File "...../multiprocessing/util.py", line 357, in _exit_function
        p.join()p.join()

  File "...../multiprocessing/process.py", line 147, in join
  File "...../multiprocessing/process.py", line 147, in join
        assert self._parent_pid == os.getpid(), 'can only join a child process'assert self._parent_pid == os.getpid(), 'can only join a child process'

AssertionErrorAssertionError: : can only join a child processcan only join a child process

[2023-11-02 11:34:53 -0400] [276288] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
```

Comment: perhaps call `mgr.shutdown` in a signal handler?